# Register plugin for dynamics 365 development in NET 6

Tags: plugins, .net-6.0, .net-7.0, dynamics-365

Until now, all the plugins that I have developed for use in dynamics 365 have been developed using version 4.6.2 of the net framework.

Is there a way to register and use a plugin developed in the NET6/7 framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep in mind this is not MS supported. Best approach is to keep track of documentation of when this operation will be supported by MS.

> Plug-in and custom workflow activity assembly projects must target .NET Framework 4.6.2. While assemblies built using later versions of the .NET Framework should generally work, if the plug-in code uses any features introduced after 4.6.2, a run-time error will occur.

Taken from [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/build-and-package#use-net-framework-462)